# MUI 5 theme - globally customize typography and color palette

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using MUI 5, I'm looking to use `ThemeProvider` and `createTheme` to set the `font-family` and color palette across all MUI components used.

I'm using this installation of mui:

```
npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components
```

Using the `Typography` component, this did not work:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: myFontFamily,
  },
})

const MyComponent = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Typography>Hello, World</Typography>
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```

while this did work:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: myFontFamily,
  },
  components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      defaultProps: {
        fontFamily: myFontFamily,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Similarly, trying to globally override the background color of `Chip`, for example, setting `theme.palette.primary` did not get applied to `<Chip color="primary" />`.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: myHexColor,
    },
  },
})

const MyComponent = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Chip label="Hello, World" color="primary" />
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```

I am struggling to find a way to globally override these styles without having to apply them to every component and component variant we want to use. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What is your starting framework, create-react-app, next.js, etc?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a CRA - I have tried everything to make the typography less giant.

Comment: I am using React and Node. Based on the answer I found below, I believe the issue here had to do with the mui style engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me out with this. It turns out that I missed this documentation on the [Styled Engine guide](https://mui.com/guides/styled-engine/) for how to use `styled-components` as the styling engine. Instead of going down that route, I ended up just installing `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` which are included with `react-select` anyways.

Comment: If you are using Material-UI, then I have no idea why you need additional library like `react-select`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean it was necessary. I meant that because I already have `react-select` as a dependency, which includes the `@emotion` packages, adding the `@emotion` packages doesn't impact the bundle for my app.

Comment: I believe Material-UI v5 is already using `@emotion`. From v4 to v5, @emotion is default style library with v5.

Comment: Right, but the docs say you can also use `styled-components` instead of `@emotion`, so I thought I'd use that since we were already using `styled-components` but I failed to read the fine print. -_-

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this will work for you.

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { StylesProvider } from '@mui/styles';

const App = () => {
  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: '#000',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#fff',
      },
      // whatever colors you want to include
      // Please refer to the following for more details
      // https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/#explore
    },
    // Here you could add global styles what you exactly want
    component: {
      typography: {
        styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          fontFamily: myFontFamily,
          // regarding the code you posted, there is no props like fontFamily, so you can't add it to the defaultProps, you can look into the Typography APIs
          https://mui.com/api/typography/#props
        },
      },
      chip: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: someColor
          // color props should work color="primary" and be applied the primary color #000
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StylesProvider>
        {/* children */}
      </StylesProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You don't need to include `ThemeProvider` for children components, just use it for root element specifically `App.js`.

I mean it's enough to use one `ThemeProvider` and one theme object in general.

If you want to customize a specific component, then please use classes and classname props for the component.
https://mui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles